# ASP Dropdown OnSelectedIndexChange event doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu, event-handling

I've gone through many articles and question about this. But still not found the answer for my case.
The function handles event. It doesn't work at all
My code:

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Popup.aspx.cs"
     Inherits="GG.UI.Popup" %>
...

<asp:DropDownList ID="LEDropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="LEDropdown_Change" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      PopulateClist();
      BindGrid();
   }
}
protected void PopulateClist()
{
   LEDropdown.Items.Clear();
   LEDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("First Item", "First");
   LEDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Second Item", "Second");
   LEDropdown.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
protected void LEDropdown_Change(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
   string selectedLE = ((DropDownList)(sender)).SelectedValue;
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Alert", "alert('" + selectedLE + "');");
}
```

I tried using `EnableViewState="true"` for this page and the Masterpage as well.Didn't work.
The function `LEDropdown_Change` was never called.
The page is still posted back after selection.

There's another button with OnClick event and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="LEDropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LEDropdown_Change" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Your dropdownlist is calling `LEDropdown_Change`

But your onchange event is called: `LegalEntityDropdown_Change`

Comment: sorry, my fault. I edited the function name so it's shorter and easier to read... not this problem. I updated my question. Thanks for spotting it.